# why can't i disable vscode hover (with the lua extension enabled)

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua, hover

i can't disable hover in vscde for Lua (I am use sumneko's lua server v3.7.0)

This bug occurs in GH  codespaces and on mac (with vs code Version: 1.83.1)

(I want to kiil it since while informative, it can be visually distracting.)

[image: with lua etension enabled,]

FYI: i've tried disabling it in the VScode editor section

[image]

and also in the Lua extensions section .

[image]

but no luck. help!

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what to do. I have search for Intellisense settings and disable there. Easy (once you know what to look for)!